# SQLite syntax error, query looks okay

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Got a problem here, not sure what's wrong...  This is in C# by the way.

```
Problem with DB: SQLite error
near "s": syntax error
```

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO information (name, picfolder, picstore) VALUES ('My Name','V:\Folder Path\Folder',1)
```

The table was created with this:

```
CREATE TABLE information (name VARCHAR(255), picfolder VARCHAR(255), picstore BOOLEAN)
```

All the c# code (requested):

```
        try
        {
            query = "CREATE TABLE information (name VARCHAR(255), picfolder VARCHAR(255), picstore BOOLEAN)";
            SQLiteCommand command1 = new SQLiteCommand(query, db); command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with DB: " + error.Message);
            db.Close(); System.IO.File.Delete(this.created_path);
            this.created_path = null; return;
        }

        try
        {
            query = "INSERT INTO information (name, picfolder, picstore) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + folder +"'," + (copy ? 1 : 0).ToString() + ")";
            SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(query, db); command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with DB: " + error.Message + "\n"+query);
            db.Close(); System.IO.File.Delete(this.created_path);
            this.created_path = null; return;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Comment: Can u also show some C# code that calls this SQL?

Comment: Your code has `VALUE` not `VALUES`.

Comment: It was suggested I try it.  I've since changed it back.

Answer (score 4):

check on \ character it maybe creating issues if the table schema is fine. I will suggest to use permeter insert instead of inline. here is the syntax.

```
stmt.text = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES (:A, :B)";
        stmt.clearParameters();
        stmt.parameters[":A"] = value
        stmt.parameters[":B"] = value
        stmt.execute();
```

Comment: you can also try true/false instead of 1 or 0 for Boolean type.

Comment: public var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();

Comment: I tried replacing the back slashes with forward slashes and still doesn't work.  But I did notice that I only have a problem when picfolder is filled in so the problem must be there.

Comment: try \\ instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized query if possible.

If not - try escaping backslashes in your value `'V:\\Folder Path\\Folder'`

Answer (score 0):

This will sound stupid but actually the way I was doing it was fine.

Problem is that the folder path I was inputting had a ' (semicolon) in it which was messing up the query.  Fixed it by having " around the values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of errors and managed to get rid of them by using SQLite from nuget.